# retrieve database php from form radio button

Tags: php

i cant retrieve data from database table .please help me)
there's too many error. cant fetch any data from database

```
&nbsp<input type="checkbox" name="model" value="Jetta" />Jetta
<input type="checkbox" name="model" value="Laguna" />Laguna
<input type="checkbox" name="model" value="Focus" />Focus
<input type="checkbox" name="model" value="Tico" />Tico
<input type="checkbox" name="model" value="Avensis" />Avensis

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" /> </div>   
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE"/>
</fieldset>

file=(test2.php)

<?      
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("carforsale");

        $sql =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM carforsale");  
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);       
        $manufacturerName = 'manufacturerName';
        $modelName = 'modelName';
        $acquisitionPrice = 'acquisitionPrice';

$model = $_POST['model'];
if ($model=="Jetta") {

include('connect.php');
$result = mysql_query("manufacturerName,modelName,acquisitionPrice FROM  
carforsale WHERE modelName='Jetta'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<td>'. $row['manufacturerName'].' </td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['modelName'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['acquisitionPrice'].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
elseif ($model=="Laguna")

$result = mysql_query("manufacturerName,modelName,acquisitionPrice FROM  
carforsale WHERE modelName='Laguna'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))        {
echo '<td style="border-left: 1px solid #eacae7;">'. 
$row['manufacturerName'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['modelName'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['acquisitionPrice'].'</td>'; 
echo '</tr>';
}
}
```

?>

*i cant retrieve data from database table .please help me
there's too many error ;'(

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Please extract *only* the relevant parts from your WoT (wall of text). It's confusing for everyone. Please

Comment: as you can see.. i am confuse too... :'(

Answer (score 1):

You have the condition

```
if ($model=="Jetta") {...
```

But $model is not being assigned anywhere

Change it to something like

```
$model = $_POST['model'];
if ($model=="Jetta") {
```

Since that wasn't assigned, the condition was false, and you don't have anything in the else at the bottom for it to do, so it basically does nothing

Comment: i want to retrieve info from database mysql... how ?

Comment: As this is partial correct it won't solves OP question

Comment: Fair enough, based on the original code posted, I was understanding the question as why the database query wasn't being executed based on the radio button.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is to scatterd, try to refactor your code in more logical block.
Also there is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

A more finetuned version of what you want to achieve

#### connect.php

```
<?php
    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $user = 'root';
   $pass = '';
   $database = 'blub';

    try { 
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database, $user, $pass);
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Could not connect to database: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
```

#### cars.php

```
<?php
    include('connect.php'); //only connect once

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM carforsale'; //default query
    $parms = array();
    $parameters = '';
    
    if (isset($_POST['model'])) {
        $sql .= ' WHERE modelName IN ({parameters})'; //adjust query when checkbox was selected
       foreach($_POST['model'] as $checkbox) {
        $parms[] = $checkbox;
        $parameters. = '?,';//forsee a placeholder for this checkbox
    }
        $parameters =      rtrim($parameters, ',');//remove last comma from ?,?,?, 
        $sql = str_replace('{parameters}', $parameters);//inject parameters when needed
    try {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); //use PDO with prepared statements instead of mysql_query (see comment above)
        $stmt->execute($parms); //inject the model name in the parameter ? in the sql if needed
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Query failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); //always check SQL errors
        exit;
    }
    
    $table  = '<table border="1">';
    $table .= '<tr><th>Manufacturer</th><th>Model</th><th>Price</th></tr>';
    foreach($rows as $row) {
            $table .= '<tr>';
            $table .= '<td>'. $row['manufacturerName'].' </td><td>'.$row['modelName'].'</td><td>'.$row['acquisitionPrice'].'</td>';
            $table .= '</tr>';
    }
    $table .= '</table>';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cars</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="checkbox" name="model[]" value="Jetta" />Jetta
                <input type="checkbox" name="model[]" value="Laguna" />Laguna
                <input type="checkbox" name="model[]" value="Focus" />Focus
                <input type="checkbox" name="model[]" value="Tico" />Tico
                <input type="checkbox" name="model[]" value="Avensis" />Avensis
                
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" /> </div>   
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <?= $table ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks DarkBee... but i need to check multiple checkbox then retrieve from database table... not immediate retrieve.. thank you for helping me.. really appreciate it. :)

Comment: I ll adjust in an hour or So.

Comment: @shby adjusted for checkboxes